# How to show related queries on a query page?

Tags: query

I am a bit new to Magento but I already have a question and I couldn't find an answer anywhere on Internet (crazy, isn't it? :))

So here's my question:

I'm on a magento given website and I search for this word: "shirts"

I already know that inside the queries db I already have related query strings similar to the one above like: blue shirts, wide collar shirts, etc.

I would like to display on the search results page for "shirts" similar search queries to this from the db with a custom link like: $link = "http://www.website.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=".$query_text;

This is useful for SEO so that a given query would pass link juice to other let's say 5 similar queries, based on the fact that google loves relevancy. So shirts would show links to blue shirts, wide collar shirts, etc.

Can this be done inside the search results sidebar or result.phtml ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change some variables on the class : Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql

set $_debug to true
set $_logAllQueries to true
you can also change $_debugFile to set a specific path